# How to recover 'unreachable blob', I deleted all the directories on my desktop by "git glean -df"

Tags: git

so I accidentally deleted all the directories by doing `git glean -df`
after which I did

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable
```

and I got a result like this

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
unreachable blob 04a0b4618ef8401650ff8ca09302314107de8314
unreachable blob 0888e4b53df74ba2dcf4109782e228fceaf70436
unreachable blob 1050ca9550f81fe82ce275780b6b91be3e80ecc1
unreachable blob 10782fec26171633f9a95fd946c7c809267bc7e9
unreachable blob 13088174b81e51d033541899bd8b65a5e6d2e661
unreachable blob 1db0d06f9d2ebbba44e824ef61b09074bce9fd49
unreachable blob 1e78b8dbac4c1197d579d0c7c90df81304da2c17
unreachable blob 2168f71bfdbd53c894d62a656eb6b9f5ec021bde
unreachable blob 24d0f035a9e3d0a8f738b4d328ad60fe815a9276
unreachable blob 2538dbd1a5f148cf710db4332e326eae21589b55
unreachable blob 25d0c4d3d0ed82c8e9f79e2c62447c09c200d71b
unreachable blob 26204a344547d90f4383ebcfa97b6d63a75cc853
unreachable blob 28689caede8aa814836f77c844b0211e2fb534ca
unreachable blob 2a984a489936f8d020d15987c311e10714d2cd21
unreachable blob 2c705786c011267f4a2d734712a6309b1c759d18
unreachable blob 2fd828d1cda9de701ad7fc9e3933c94c01dcdc4d
```

I opened a few of them, although the name seem to be lost but I think these are the deleted files. Is there a way I can put them in a folder/directory or recover them from here?

I am new to git and did a huge mistake trying to remove the untracked files.

Comment: The directories and files removed by `git clean -df` were untracked. If you never added or committed them before they were cleaned, no blobs were created from them. The unreachable blobs in the repo almost have nothing to do with the lost files.

Answer (score 0):

`git clean` shouldn't create any problems like that, it will leave the .git dir intact and will ignore any git directories it finds inside your project.

It's more likely that those unreachable blobs existed before. They might not be a problem, as it just means that you have git objects that it doesn't know how to use, for example if you abort some operations while they're running. If you suspect you have any work missing then [this guide might help](https://schacon.github.io/git/user-manual.html#dangling-objects).

Comment: yea I didn't realize I was at the desktop and I executed git clean -f -d while removed all the files on my desktop. All the folders and files. D o you have any idea how and If I can recover them. I am using a MAC

Comment: Huh, `git clean` should only do anything if it's inside a git repo. Have you made your desktop or parent directory into a git repo? If so, the only way you'll be able to recover any files is if you committed them to the git repo or backed them up elsewhere.